# Merging Pandas Dataframe values, but retaining column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with several rows that based on the id column are duplicates of each other, except the rest of the values in their respective rows are not duplicates. My goal is to merge these rows into a single row, without losing the data from the rest of their columns.

[image]

I would like the expected result to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Left ID', 'left_side'])['Right ID'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))`

Comment: How would this work if I wanted to do this on the "Right_Side" column - I am trying it right now and it keeps failing

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to do it. This will group by both "Left ID" and "left_side", but I assume both are always grouped together. It will then take the unique values of "Right ID" and store it as an array in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[35, 'A', 1405], [35, 'A', 1404], [35, 'A', 79837],[3, 'B', 45277]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Left ID', 'left_side', 'Right ID']) 

df_out = df.groupby(['Left ID', 'left_side'])['Right ID'].unique().reset_index()
```